# Magento 2 - Message queue stopped working after update to Magento 2.4.5-p1

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

Since we've updated from Magento 2.4.4 to Magento 2.4.5-p1 the message queue (we're using RabbitMQ) stopped working. For example when we update products in bulk, the message is still 'Message added to the queue' but nothing changes. Anyone else experiencing this problem?

I tried disabling Magento_WebapiAsync and Magento_Amqp as a hofit, but then I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can you try and manually trigger the consumer to see if the bulk endpoint queue is processed (you'll need amqp enabled though)

```
bin/magento queue:consumers:start async.operations.all
```

If this works and the queue is emptied, then you may need to check your env.php settings to make sure your settings are not omitting the consumer that handles bulk updates.

an example setup would be:

```
<?php
return [
  // ...
  'cron_consumers_runner' => [
    'cron_run' => true, // if you want cron to run the consumers..
    'max_messages' => 10000,
    'consumers' => [
        'async.operations.all',
        // any other consumers ..
    ]
  ],
  // ...
];
```

you can get a full list of consumers to add:

```
php bin/magento queue:consumers:list
```